# YUI3 - Errors don't appear in Firebug - Y.on('available

Tags: javascript, console.log

solution, you have to call the parameter in the responding function from the Y.on('available', myFunction, domelement').  so function myFunction(e)

Rewriting this,

If I used the following code, (game isn't defined),

```
function myFunction () {
    console.log(game);
}

Y.on('available',myFunction,#domElement);
```

I don't get an error in my console for game, which isn't defined (should be a reference error).

Any idea why? Or how I can get those errors to show in the console?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have *hame* (again misspelled) somewhere else in your code.

Comment: There's a "dropdown" in the "Console" button, with which you can control the information shown in the console. Are you sure your console shows JS errors?

Comment: Don't have the variable misspelled anywhere else. I've even added console.log('done'+hame) and nothing shows up.  It also stops all code afterwards (which makes sense), just doesn't show the error.

Yes, have javascript errors on. It shows other errors, but not all.

Comment: If you test with a script containing these two lines only, do you get an error message?

Comment: Just did a bit more investigation (sorry should have done it before I posted).  I'm using YUI.  It seems that when I use Y.on('available',function,node), it ignores some console.log errors when it travels to that function.  Not sure why.

Comment: Posted on YUI's forums to see if I get the answer.  thanks!